# Can't shutdown my pc runing windows 8.1 after an incident

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, kali-linux

A week ago after shutting down my PC, the next time when I turned it on again, it didn't boot.
After reinstalling Kali Linux, it worked again, however all of the system apps were gone. That got fixed by itself after a few days.

Now the only problem is that I can't shut it down. Every time I try to, the monitor goes off then with a single move of mouse it turns up again like it was sleeping.

PS: I'm triple booting windows 8.1 and Kali and Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: windows 8.1.read the title

Comment: Hey is this happening to you too.when i click on a link like add comment it opens a popup. i don't remember superuser been using ads

Comment: hey my problem was soled yesterday by it self.i think the problem was a virus or after i used force shutdown one time it got fixed.

Answer (score -4):

It is normal because you installed to many OS to PC.The PC will be unstable.Try to force shutdown os you are using.I don't know how to force shutdown In Linux But in Windows You can Enter This Command To Command Prompt:"shutdown /f /s"
(Sorry For bad English)

Comment: Do you have any source to back this? [People have been multi-booting 100+ OSes simultaneously](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?143973-A-grub-menu-booting-100-systems-of-Dos-Windows-Linux-BSD-and-Solaris).

Comment: You say it is simultaneously. i think they use Virtual OS's.The Virtual OS will be more stable than normal two OS

Comment: Read that thread. It contains details on how they were multi-booted, so these weren't virtual machines. Anyway, multiple OSes installed in parallel don't affect each other at all.